# I am getting 500 Internal server error in jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, http-status-code-500

Getting 500 internal server error code.

At the last line of the above snapshot, one can see that ${unique_id_up_1} is not getting passed as the id, it is getting passed as it is, that is the reason i am getting 500 error response. I extracted it from previous response using json extractor.
In some case id is passed, in some case it is getting passed as it is.
Please someone help with this.[Request Body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bshVI.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `${unique_id_up_1}` variable is not defined, you can double check it using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter).

In order to get comprehensive help you need to provide at least partial response so we could come up with proper relevant [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) configuration for extraction of the neccessary piece of response data.

Comment: In response nothing is coming, it is showing 500 error, this ${unique_id_up_1} variable is getting passed correctly in some requests and not in some requests..when i run in loop